# How to paint on pixmaps inside a QList<QPixmap>?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to generate pixmaps with the following code

```
QList<QPixmap> pixmapList;
for (int i=0;i<50;++i){
    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap(10050,10050);
    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
    pixmapList<<pixmap;
}
```

The above part works find. And I would like to paint on those pixmaps later, e.g.

```
QPixmap pixmap = pixmapList[10];
QPainter painter(&pixmap);
painter.drawPixmap(....); // this pixmap is 10*10
pixmapList[10]=pixmap;
```

or

```
QPainter painter(&pixmapList[10]);
painter.drawPixmap(....); // this pixmap is 10*10
```

but they both gave me "QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2". May I ask the right way to paint on pixmaps in the pixmapList? Thanks very much!

Comment: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/QPainter::begin:Paint_device_returned_engine_==_0_(Known_Issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is OK, except that the pixmaps are too big (they occupy ~400MBytes each).

After making the pixmaps smaller, it works fine (shown for Qt 5):

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPainter>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);
   QList<QPixmap> pixmapList;
   for (int i=0;i<50;++i){
      QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap(1000,1000);
      pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
      pixmapList<<pixmap;
   }
   QPainter painter(&pixmapList[10]);
   painter.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
   return 0;
}
```